# Como tomar valor de una grilla y adjuntarla a otra grilla?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net, visual-studio-2017

les paso a comentar mi necesidad.
tengo dos formularios "A" con punto de venta, y "B" con busqueda de articulo, cada uno con una grilla.
como hago para que cuando selecciono el articulo de la grilla del formulario "B", se cargue en la grilla del formulario "A"?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow, da un [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y revisa [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas formular una pregunta que sea aceptada por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que plantas se resuelve comunicando los formularios, aqui

[Comunicar Formularios](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2014/05/comunicar-formularios.html)

explica como puede lograrlo, no lo explico con dos grids, pero si envio los datos seleccionados del grid del form hijo B al form padre A

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay varias formas de resolverlo

- usando interfaces
- usando eventos

ambas permiten desacoplar la interaccion y pasar los datos

Para la primera defines la interfaz como ser

```
interface IForm{
   void ArticuloSeleccionado(Articulo item);
}
```

entonces en el form padre implementas la interfaz

```
public class FormPrincipal : Form, IForm {

    //codigo del form

    //implementas el metodo de la interfaz que recibe el articulo
    public void ArticuloSeleccionado(Articulo item)
    {
       //aqui agregas la row al grid
    }

    private void button1_Click(...){
      frmArticulo frm = new frmArticulo(this);
      frm.Show()
    } 
}
```

Es importante ese `this` en el constructor del form hijo al instanciarlo

Despues el form hijo envias la seleccion teniendo la instancia

```
public class frmArticulo : Form{

     private IForm _form;

     public frmBuscar(IForm form){ //este es el constructor
          _form = form;
     }

     private void gridview1_DoubleClick(...)
     {
         //aqui conviertes los datos a la entidad articulo
         _form.ArticuloSeleccionado(...);
     }
 }
```